# PHP is_uploaded_file fails for iOS app

Tags: php, ios, file-upload

I'm writing the PHP/webserver side of an image upload for an iOS app. Using an html file I can upload an image to my script just fine. I've even written a Perl LWP script to post an image with no problems.

When the iOS app uploads an image it fails when I call is_uploaded_file. Sending back the $_FILES var in the json response show us what we expect for a file upload. Also I do a file_exists on the tmp_name and that fails as well.

Is there anything else I can look at in the request to determine what is going wrong? I'd like to be able to indicate what's wrong with the post request.

Here's the block of code where it stop processing the image upload:

```
    //Check for valid upload
    if(!is_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'])) {
        $this->errors['upload_2'] = $photoErrorString;
        $this->errors['files'] = $_FILES;
        $this->errors['image_uploaded'] = file_exists($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name']);
        error_log("uploadPhoto: upload_2");
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: What value is in `$_FILES['photo']['error']`? If it's anything OTHER than `0`, the upload failed. The error codes are documented here: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php. Checking for the presence of the temporary file is a bad way to verify an upload succeeded.

Comment: @MarcB before the check I posted above I do have `if($_FILES['photo']['error'] != UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {` before the is_uploaded_file check which has always indicated that the upload was fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i know you cannot upload a image or photo from iOS app directly using PHP scripts.

You have to send 64 bit encode from the iOS app to the script responsible for the file upload as a simple POST. Then that script will firstly decode your photo's string and then PHP script will create the image from the string only to upload.

Code will be something like:

```
$filedb = $path_to_dir.$file_name_of_the_photo;
$profile_pic = $_POST['profile_pic'];
$profile_pic= base64_decode($profile_pic);
if(($img = @imagecreatefromstring($profile_pic)) != FALSE) 
{
  if(imagepng($img,$filedb))//will create image and save it to the path from the filedb with the name in variable file_name_of_the_photo
  {
imagedestroy($img);// distroy the string of the image after successful upload
// do other updates to database if required
  }
  else //cannot create imagepng Error
  { 
//do what required
  }
}
```

Hope this will work.

Comment: Thanks. This put on the right path and in fact the images was being sent raw instead of base64 encoded.

Answer (score 1):

Linked below is a really nice NSData base64 category.
If you're unfamiliar with categories in Obj-C, they're basically stock objects that we know and love with some added methods (in this case, base64 encoding/decoding).
This class is really simple to drop into an existing project.
Enjoy.

http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/06/base64-encoding-options-on-mac-and.html

Comment: This looks like its doing exactly what needs to be done in the iOS app. I'll pass the link along to the iOS developer that is working on this project.